# Moving files from one linux server to another using scp

Tags: linux, scp

I want to move some files from one server to another . I want the public_html directory from server 1 to be transferred to server 2 . Can anyone give me the syntax to do so ? rsync keeps crashing my server after some hours . I'm using centos 7 .

Comment: You should edit your question to provide more detail such as the rsync command you used and the output of that command.

Comment: Hi using rsync my server crashes . I don't know why but I will investigate this crash issue and let you know if I find something . for know I will check to see if scp works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
scp -r <source path> <user_name>@<ip of server_2>:/<destination path>
```

Ex-

```
scp -r ./public_html movi@10.1.1.1:/home/movi
```

Comment: Will this scp transfer remove the source files ? I don't want the source files to be deleted after transfer is complete .

Comment: Nope. It will not remove the source.

Comment: [`man scp`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/scp) : No; `scp` **copies** files and may overwrite target files but does nothing to the sources...

Answer (score 0):

You should use SCP when you want to do a one copy. And Rsync if you want to continues sync directories or files.

I'm using the following syntax for syncing over SSH

```
rsync -ah --delete -e ssh /path/to/source-folder user@server:/path/to/destination-folder
```

Don't worry about the **--delete** flag. That options only deletes files and folders in the destination folder when it doesn't exists in the source folder

I'm having a hard time thinking that this should cause your servers to crash. Please provide us with your rsync command so that we could look into this issue.

Br
Sanderp